# Updating database schema

Tags: symfony

I try to run :

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

but I have this exception:

```
Invalid mapping file 'App.Application.Sonata.UserBundle.Entity.Group.orm.xm
  l' for class 'App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\Group'.
```

I extended SonataUserBundle on my App\Application folder. The entities are present on App\Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity.

On my doctrine file, I mapped like that:

```
orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
            SonataUserBundle: ~
            FOSUserBundle: ~
            ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
```

But still can't update schema.

Comment: Have you checked your dir path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might be file is not in same directory.

Comment: Yes exactly, the problem is related to the path indicated on the xml file. I addedd App\ to the full path, and now works! thanks all

Comment: yes that is the issue